# Writing a CREATE TABLE, keep getting errors

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

Can anyone look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I've looked up different ways to write it and changed it several times but keep getting different errors. I've pasted the current error, another one I've gotten is "missing left parenthesis" even when I have them all entered.

Error starting at line 1 in command:

```
CREATE TABLE book(
ISBN VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
AUTHORF_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
AUTHORL_NAME VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
LIST_PRICE NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
QO_H INTEGER NOT NULL
)


Error at Command Line:1 Column:14
Error report:
      SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Do you already have an object named `book`?

Comment: The error is pretty clear isn't it?

Comment: select * from user_objects where object_name = 'BOOK';

Answer (score 2):

You already have a book table in your database.  Tablenames must be unique.

Comment: To be precise: there is already an *object* name `BOOK`. Could also be a view, a materialized view, an object type, ...

Comment: Namespace information here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129 See item 8 under "Database Object Naming Rules"